# How to get the file names from a directory with a loop?

Tags: batch-file

I tried to get all file names in directory `input` but it does not work for me.

```
@echo off

:start
cls
FOR /D %%i IN ("input*") DO python index.py %%i
TIMEOUT /T 20
exit
```

Comment: Try this, `cd input` `for \r %%i IN (*) DO python index.py %%i`. Those are two different lines. I added switch `\r` if you want recursively get file name's from aubfolders as well, you can remove it if not.

Comment: Remove the `/D` option to get file returned and use the [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html): `for %%I in ("input\*.*") do echo %%~nxI`

Comment: It does not work, I can not see echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all file names (not directory names) in the `input` directory, use the following. It will produce all file names that are not directories and run the python command on them. Always quote path names in case there are spaces or other special characters in them.

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "input"') DO (
    "C:\venv\py36-64\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\path\to\index.py" "%%~i"
)
```

If the `python.exe` directory is in the PATH variable and `index.py` is always in the parent directory of `input`, then you could use this.

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /A:-D "input"') DO (
    "python.exe" "..\index.py" "%%~i"
)
```